# How to find and replace a particular string by increasing its numerical part?

Tags: sed, perl, awk

My input file is,

```
ami41 ami56
ami23
ami67
ami45 ami34 ami88
jama66
tumi234 bichi23455
susami345
```

Using a single command line I need the output as,

```
ami42 ami57
ami24
ami68
ami46 ami35 ami89
jama66
tumi234 bichi23455
susami345
```

I used the command,

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1+1/eg' inputfile
```

But I got the output file as,

```
ami42 ami57
ami24
ami68
ami46 ami35 ami89
jama67
tumi235 bichi23456
susami346
```

i.e. all numerics with all types strings are increased. But I need the numerical only with `ami` string to be increased. Could anyone kindly suggest me some better command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Perl lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=ami)(\d+)/$1+1/eg' inputfile
ami42 ami57
ami24
ami68
ami46 ami35 ami89
jama66
tumi234 bichi23455
susami346
```

The `(?=<ami)` tells Perl to look for `ami` before matching the rest of the pattern, but not actually include it in the match.

Comment: It is useful. Thanks. But I need "susami345" in the output file where this 'perl' command is giving "susami346". Can you please give some modified version of 'perl' command which can handle only "ami" string?

Comment: @tamal just add a word boundary marker: `\bami` instead of `ami`.

Comment: If I want to replace the string "ami007" to "ami008" by your 'perl' command. But it is actually replacing "ami007" to "ami8". Can you kindly suggest some solution ?

Comment: Instead of `(?<=ami)(\d+)` use `(?<=ami0*)[1-9]\d*`.

Comment: This says that  "Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<=ami*)(\d*)/ at -e line 1.

Comment: Hmm. Try `perl -pe 's/(?<=ami)(0*)(\d+)/$1.($2+1)/eg' inputfile`.

Comment: Working. But it replaces "ami0009" to "ami00010", and "ami0099" to "ami00100". I need it as "ami0009" to "ami0010" and "ami0099" to "ami0100". Please advice some more modification.

Comment: @tamal that's all I can say unless all the numbers have some fixed width.