# Find and replacement of the numerical part of a particular string with increased value using terminal command

Tags: command-line, python, sed, perl, awk

The inputfile is,

```
test00.dat test07.dat test03.dat
aram22.dat test09.dat aram09.dat
test13.dat
```

I need the output file as

```
test01.dat test08.dat test04.dat
aram22.dat test10.dat aram09.dat
test14.dat
```

i.e. the numerical string associated with `test` is increased by unity. I need a suitable terminal command-line to perform this operation.

Especially, I need to know the conversion mechanism of 'test09.dat' to 'test10.dat' change.

Comment: Per-file or in a directory? Recursively or "flat"?

Comment: In a single 'input.txt' file all strings are written and I need the output written in the mentioned manner in 'output.txt' file. It will be  more convenient if I can do it in recursive manner. For example, from test00.dat to test99.dat.

Comment: I see, you mean *text inside a file*.

Comment: Do all searched strings end with `.dat` (that would limit the search)?

Comment: Yes, text inside a file. All strings end with .dat

Comment: but the solution there can not convert from test09.dat to test10.dat @KasiyA

Comment: I know. You have to learn how to extend them to solve your current question :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `perl` oneliner to do the transformation:

```
echo "test00.dat test09.dat aram22.dat" | perl -pe 's/test\K(\d+)/sprintf "%02d", $1+1/eg'
```

Result:

```
test01.dat test10.dat aram22.dat
```

To use your input file:

```
$ perl -pe 's/test\K(\d+)/sprintf "%02d", $1+1/eg' your_file
test01.dat test08.dat test04.dat
aram22.dat test10.dat aram09.dat
test14.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick'n'dirty solution based on [How to find and replace a particular string by increasing its numerical part?](https://askubuntu.com/q/589714/283843)

```
echo "test00.dat test07.dat aram22.dat" | perl -pe 's/(?<=test)(\d+)/$1+1/eg' | sed -e 's/test\([0-9]\)\./test0\1/g'
test01dat test08dat aram22.dat
```

Note that there is an ugly hack in my command: perl outputs test1.dat and I use sed to fix it to test01.dat

Answer (score 0):

The script below assumes the numbers in the words occur *consecutively* in the filenames (e.g. `file_123.dat`, not `file12something345.dat`), and the names of the files are *unique*.

#### What it does

- It searches the file for words with integers in the name.
- It will convert those (consecutive) integers int "real" integers (values), which will remove the leading zeros.
- Add one to the value
- Then compare the "original" length of the number-string with the edited value, adding leading zeros if the edited string is shorter.

Example:

```
test999.dat test07.dat test03.dat
aram22.dat test09.dat aram09.dat
test0000013.dat
```

outputs:

```
test1000.dat test08.dat test04.dat
aram22.dat test10.dat aram09.dat
test0000014.dat
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
for w in [w for w in file.split() if w.startswith("test")]:
    try:
        found = "".join([ch for ch in w if ch.isdigit()])
        replace = (len(found), str(int(found)+1))
        file = file.replace(w, w.replace(found, replace[1].zfill(replace[0])))
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(file.strip())
```

#### How to use

1. Copy it into an empty file, save it as `add_one.py`
2. Run it with the file as an argument by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/add_one.py '</path/to/file>`
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here you're a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
    exit
fi

names=$(cat "$1" | sort)

for i in $names; do
    filename=${i%.*}
    extension=${i##*.}
    number=${filename: -2:2}
    name=${filename//[0-9]}
    fnumber=$(printf "%02d\n" $((${number#0}+1)))
    if [[ "$name" == "test" ]]; then
        echo "${name}${fnumber}.${extension}"
    else
        echo "$i"
    fi    
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately your script does not preserve the expected output. Moreover it seems that OP only wants `test.*dat` to be incremented, not `aram.*.dat`

Comment: Solved, I don't read the original purpose of the question. I thought that it should increment a unit on all filenames.